# Regex for the any length - positive and negative integer and long in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to pass date like `20140101` as its data type is integer in meta file so i have tried many regex but it always return `false`. Another column that is of type `long` with data like `0000000000000`. So what is regex for both `integer` and `long` separate. Thanks

Comment: What reges have you tried?

Comment: why don't you convert date to long format?

Comment: Ya i am working on the same as well.

Comment: I have tried this one "(\\d+)|([\\+-]?\\d+)" regex.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a regex like this one should work for an integer:

```
(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})
```

[EXAMPLE](https://regex101.com/r/rF3xT5/1)

Assuming your date occupies the last digits of the long here is the regex you should use :

```
\d{5}(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})
```

[EXAMPLE](https://regex101.com/r/gU1eG0/1)

In Java you should be able to get the date object you seek with:

```
    String toParse = "20140102";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(toParse);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        int month = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
        int day = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));

        System.out.println(new Date(year - 1900, month - 1, day));
    }
```

You can try it [HERE](http://ideone.com/F9Y4fe)

Comment: This is confusing: you can't really use `$1` etc. Consider posting correct code.

Comment: Well this is "pseudo-code". I'm just giving an example of what he could do.

Comment: You are explicitly saying "In Java" and calling a Java constructor using incorrect data, according to your comment "...your regex matches".

Comment: Don't post links - the code should be here. And it hasn't been fixed.

Comment: Did you check the test output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79769/discussion-between-yami-and-laune).

Comment: We could discuss whether `find` or `matches` is preferable, but I guess it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a string like 20140101 and you have to test it with regex you can use this regex:

/[0-9]{8}/

Example:

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MatcherExample {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text    =
        "This is the text to be searched " +
        "for occurrences of the http:// pattern.";

    String patternString = "/[0-9]{8}/";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    boolean matches = matcher.matches();
}
```

}

You could use https://regex101.com/ to test regex.

Comment: could you hel me on the long one because thhe lenght of long data is not fixed?

Comment: Regex are for strings. You could store long and int like strings: int i = 1; String iString = ""+i;

Comment: Using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?